# how to call a id in different division in html

Tags: javascript, css, html

im using an html5 single page template  ....i have 3 text box, one text area and a clear button....the 3 text box and  clear button are in the same div....the text area  is in another div... i want to clear the all text  box by clicking the clear button,,,,in my code the 3 text box only clear...the 4th one does not clear..

```
<div>
    <input name="subject" type="text"  id="subject" placeholder="Your Subject">
    <input name="email" type="text"  id="email" placeholder="Your     Email"">      
    <div>
        <button type="reset" id="reset"  value="Clear" >clear</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <textarea name="message" rows="10" class="form-control" id="message" >
    <textarea>
</div>
```

i want to clear the all text box by this clear button
plz give a solution to solve this problem....im a beginner!

thank u

Comment: *".. i have 3 text box, one text area  .."*; but your code shows 2 textboxes and 2 textareas

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/8ZJMf/ ...?

Comment: share your jquery code or a jsfiddle.

Comment: Where is your js code? Can you show it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.... You can also use jquery **$** selector instead of **document.getElementById**

Because you are not using **form** .  So, the form wont be reset using **reset** type input

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function resetForm() {
                document.getElementById("subject").value = "";
                document.getElementById("email").value = "";
                document.getElementById("message").value = "";
            }

        </script>
    </head>
 <body>
        <div>
            <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Your Subject" />
            <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Your     Email" />
            <div>
                <button type="button" id="reset" onclick="resetForm()" value="Clear">
                    clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea name="message" rows="10" class="form-control" id="message">
            </textarea>
        </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

u need to give all your input fields inside a form tag

```
<form>
  <div> 
    <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Your Subject"> 
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Your Email"> 
  <div> 
    <textarea name="message" rows="10" class="form-control" id="message" > </textarea> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="reset" id="reset" value="Clear" >clear</button> </div> 
   </div> 
  </form>
```

From this reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-button-type-reset-state

> Reset Button If the element has a form owner and the element's
>   Document is fully active, the element must reset the form owner. ...
>   The form attribute is used to explicitly associate the button element
>   with its form owner.

Answer (score 0):

***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZJMf/1/)***
*jQuery Code*

```
$('#reset').click(function () {
    $('.remove input', '.remove textarea').val('');
});
```

Comment: What has jQuery got to do with anything here? The Op has also not tagged the question with jQuery! jQuery is *not* the solution to anything under the sun and earth.